# The Magic Eden API is only giving the {} in the json response?

Tags: python, nft

I'm trying to get wallet activity through the Magic Eden API. The documentation provides an example:

```
import requests

url = "api-devnet.magiceden.dev/v2/wallets/4wejSnr97csngztZ5SU7A6iZRXJD7B3Y1R1koCQ5NjmD/activities?offset=0&limit=100"

payload={}
headers = {}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

I'm changing the url to `http://api-devnet.magiceden.dev/v2/wallets/MYWALLET/activities?offset=0&limit=100`, but it just returns the {} sign to me. There were no example headers or payload.

Comment: This is likely because you should be using `response.content` or `response.content.decode("utf-8")`

Comment: This is because you are sending empty headers. Every http request needs basic headers otherwise it will be considered as `400 - Bad Request`.


Use `requests.get(url)` instead of `requests.request`.

Comment: Thanks guys. The mistake was that I forgot to change the link to the `api-main net.magiceden.dev / v2`

Answer (score 0):

Add api key as authorization in header